# How to access data in a Spark Dataset Column

Tags: api, apache-spark, split, apache-spark-sql, col

I have a Dataframe like this:

```
+------+---+
|  Name|Age|
+------+---+
|A-2   | 26|
|B-1   | 30|
|C-3   | 20|
+------+---+

scala> p.select("Name", "Age")
res2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Name: string, Age: string]
```

We can see clearly here that the data in the columns are of type `String`

I want to transform the `Name` column with a `split("-")` like method to get only the first part of it (i.e A, B, C).
But type `Column` in spark doesn't have such a method, so i'm thinking how to get the 'string' inside of the Column so i can perform the `split` operation.

Does anyone know what should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [functions.split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#split(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20java.lang.String)) method

```
df.select(split(col("Name"), "-").getItem(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Split function available for spark dataframe. See the example below.

```
//Creating Test Data
val df = Seq(("A-2", 26)
  , ("B-1", 30)
  , ("C-3", 20)
).toDF("name", "age")

df.withColumn("new_name", split(col("name"),"-")(0)).show(false)

+----+---+--------+
|name|age|new_name|
+----+---+--------+
|A-2 |26 |A       |
|B-1 |30 |B       |
|C-3 |20 |C       |
+----+---+--------+
```